# C# Static counter not incrementing - why?

Tags: c#, static

New to passing static counters and I'm stuck. I want to count the instances of the Member() class and then put that value as the Member's Id number when I add them to an ObservableCollection, called _members in this case.

In my Member class:

```
    // Total numbers of instances that have been created
    public static int NumMembers { get; protected set; }

    // Static constructor initializes NumMembers
    static Member()
    {
        NumMembers = 0;
    }
    public Member(string img, int mbrnum, string mbrname, string phonenum, string mbradd, List<string> rtls)
    {
        // Increment member count and assign member number.
        NumMembers++;
        MemberNumber = NumMembers;

        Img = img;
        MemberName = mbrname;
        MemberPhone = phonenum;
        MemberAddress = mbradd;
        Rentals = rtls;
    } // Working ctor
```

In my main window:

```
        _members.Add(new Member()
        {
            Img = "Default.jpg",
            MemberNumber = 0,
            MemberName = "Joe Snow",
            MemberPhone = "0549880974",
            MemberAddress = "Mars",
            Rentals = new List<string>()
            {
                "Mrs. Brown's Boys D'Movie",
                "Jersey Boys"
            }
        });
```

If I hard-code the MemberNumber to any number in the main window it displays correctly so I know I'm doing something wrong here but I'm honestly a bit lost as to what's the snag. A fresh pair of eyeballs with more experience than me would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You're not calling the constructor you've shown. You're calling a parameterless constructor (that you've not shown us) and then, after that has been called, explicitly setting `MemberNumber` to `0` in that final piece of code.

Comment: You're not calling the correct CTOR in your example. You're calling  a parameterless CTOR.

Comment: As a side note; you should probably be using `Interlocked.Increment` here, if you want it to be accurate under concurrent load

Comment: @MarcGravell As a side-question: Would it also help to let the property access a `volatile` static member variable? Would that be equivalent?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar no; volatile does not guarantee atomic increments - for example: "thread A reads the field value, as volatile = 4", "thread B reads the field value, as volatile = 4", "thread A increments the local value and assigns to the field value, as volatile = 5", "thread B increments the local value and assigns to the field value, as volatile = 5" - so two increments, all using `volatile`, yet it ends up only incremented by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incremented the counter in the constructor that takes parameters. But the way you are instantiating the Member object you are calling the default/empty constructor so you counter is never updated.
You should call the constructor that you created or you should add the constructor in the default constructor and all subsequent constructors should call the default as well.

Below I added the counter int default constructor and made the subesquent constructor call it

```
// Total numbers of instances that have been created
    public static int NumMembers { get; protected set; }

    // Static constructor initializes NumMembers
    static Member()
    {
        NumMembers = 0;
    }

    public Member()
    {
        // Increment member count and assign member number.
        NumMembers++;
    }
    public Member(string img, int mbrnum, string mbrname, string phonenum, string mbradd, List<string> rtls)
:this()
    {
        MemberNumber = NumMembers;
        Img = img;
        MemberName = mbrname;
        MemberPhone = phonenum;
        MemberAddress = mbradd;
        Rentals = rtls;
    } // Working ctor
```

`

Comment: No, note the parameterless constructor there too and the `this()` call on the parameterized one.

Comment: This answer is only part of the solution. While it makes sure that `NumMembers` is incremented correctly, it doesn't help the fact that in the OP's code the `MemberNumber` propery is overridden.

Comment: He certainly didn't copy/paste! The increment ID is working perfectly now and I understand how it operates too - thanks Van! The MemberNumber property was being overridden in the above but that was just me trying out different ways to see if it'd work.

Comment: @user2966419 ok my bad, sorry guys. Read too fast. No excuse.

Answer (score 1):

The fact you call a constructor first and then set the properties probably overwrites the correct member number with 0, no matter which constructor you call. Also, you're not calling the constructor that actually increments the `NumMembers` property, but the parameterless constructor.

**The proper solution to your problem**

Make the `MemberNumber` property read only and make sure it is only set upon construction of the object. That way you will prevent the property from accidentially being overwritten with other values.

Make this the parameterless constructor:

```
public Member()
{
    // Increment member count and assign member number.
    NumMembers++;
    MemberNumber = NumMembers;
}
```

It increments the static property and assigns the new member number to this instance. *This is the only time the `MemberNumber` property is assigned* and it actually also *the only time the `NumMembers` property may be incremented!*.

Make sure to call this constructor from *all other constructors available*:

```
public Member(string img, ...) : this()
{
    Img = img;
    ...
}
```

Note the **`: this()`** part!

Declare the `MemberNumber` property as follows to make sure it can not be changed from "outside":

```
public int MemberNumber
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the correct constructor:

```
_members.Add(new Member("Default.jpg", 0, "Joe Snow", "0549880974", "Mars", 
    new List<string>
    {
        "Mrs. Brown's Boys D'Movie",
        "Jersey Boys"
    }));
```

But it seems that the second parameter `mbrnum` is useless since you are handling this counter in a static member, which is by the way highly not recommended for thread safety issues (but this is not your question here).